# Long exposure water shots tutorial for dummies?

Tags: long-exposure, tutorial, water

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make the water silky in water/beach photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21723/how-do-i-make-the-water-silky-in-water-beach-photography)

I want to start to do some long exposure shots of water like these:

[image]
picture from noticeeverything

So I don't know where I should start to learn this. Is there any step to step tutorial for a Sony DSC-HX100V camera?

Comment: I think we actualg have some pretty good tutorials on that _here_ (look under [tag:water]), and although none are for your specific model I don't think that should matter too much.

Answer (score 4):

Those are easy actually but with the right tools.

The key is that you need a long exposure which requires:

- Stable support like a sturdy tripod.
- Long shutter-speed which you dial-in in Shutter-Priority or Manual mode.
- A low ISO, to maximize shutter-speed.
- A small aperture, to maximize shutter-speed.
- A ND density filter should the previous two steps not result in a slow enough shutter-speed.

The shutter-speed you need depends on the speed of water and how blurry you want the results. 2s should be a minimum, but you may easily need 15s or more. Your camera can do 30s but not close the aperture below F/8, so if you do this when its bright you will most likely need the ND filter. You will also have to hold it by hand during the entire exposure since I do not thing your cameras has a filter-thread.